# Jquery menu color change with PHP in it

Tags: php, jquery, menu, colors

i wanna apply a affect where my links gets a new color each time i press them... This i believe can be done with a jquery function, however my link are not linked to anything just som PHP so I cant make it work but here is what i wanna do:

```
Make this: http://jsfiddle.net/wD6C6/

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/cnMdb/31/
```

Each time i press the links, they change color to for example blue.

Hope u guys can help me with this tricky one because my links are to some php and not just some # :)

Comment: I don't really understand what your question is. Also, without the PHP code that you use to generate the links, it's pretty difficult to provide a proper answer to this.

Comment: Since those links are not `#`, why does it matter whether they change color or not?

Answer (score 1):

You should add an `onclick` event to the links, to call a javascript function to change the background color of the link,  and a `target="_blank"`, to open the link in a new tab, so that a user can see the changed background color of the clicked link.

Or you can call the php pages using Ajax (I guess you meant this by saying "my links are to some php and not just some #"), and load the `responseText` to a part of the current page, so that the difference you make in the general design can be seen.

But if it is not the answer you seek for, then your question really needs some more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that I've understood your problem but...

Based on:

```
<div id="foo">
   <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Click</a>
   <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com"  target="_blank">Click</a>
</div>
```

And whether the links point to php or are created by php should make do difference, you can do:

```
$(function(){
  $("#foo a").click(function(){
    var r=Math.floor(Math.random()*256-1);
    var g=Math.floor(Math.random()*256-1);
    var b=Math.floor(Math.random()*256-1);
    rgb = "rgb(" + [r,b,g].toString() + ")";
    $(this).css("color", rgb);
  });
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kentcoast/6LYZx/)to play with.

Comment: rgb = "rgb(" + [r,b,g].toString() + ")";  -  Oh I like that!